# How can i get class from Object parameter?

Tags: java, object

If i put object of A class as argument of `someMeth(Object o)`, how can i access to this object methods? I cant change or overrdie `someMeth(Object o)`.

```
...
void someMeth(Object o) {
     o.setS("example"); -- exception : setS() is undefined for type Object
}
...
class A {
    private String s;
    String getS () {
        return s;
    }
    void setS(String value) {
        s = value;
    }

}
...
someMeth(new A());
```

Comment: this is just bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the object `o` to they type `A` like so:

```
A newObj = (A) o;
```

Then you can do:

```
newObj.setS("example");
```

Or a shorter, one line version:

```
((A)o).setS("example");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert type of reference:

```
void someMeth(Object o) {
     if (o instanceof A) {
         ((A) o).setS("example");
     }
}
```

Comment: but you can do that without determinating of o instantiates

Comment: If your intent is "call concrete method", you determine instance automatically in your mind. If you have several instances, you need to create `interface` with method `setS()` and convert `o` to your interface type. If you'll remove `if` statement and object won't instance of `A` you can catch `ClassCastException`.